# Can Sites Detect Bots Through Iframes on Another Site?

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I am using python and selenium to scrape data. The site holding the data has quite strong bot detection mechanisms so it is very difficult to scrape it directly.

However, the data is available through an aggregation site (similar to a comparison site for things like insurance). The data is within an iframe which links back to the target site.

Can the target site implement it's bot detection measures through the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Every page has a file called 'robots.txt' which tells search engine crawlers which URLs the crawler can access on your site. This is used mainly to avoid overloading your site with requests; it is not a mechanism for keeping a web page out of Google.

Before scraping any website you should read its robots.txt file to avoid any legal thing or just for safe side.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/web-scraping-legal-or-illegal/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/web-scrapping-legal-or-illegal/)